# How to map items with onPress in each of them in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have an array of days

Array: `[Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday]`

I am mapping this on the screen using the below code:

```
<ScrollView
  horizontal={true}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.horizontalView}>
  {weekArray.map((item, key) => ((
        <Text key={key} style={styles.TextStyle}>
          {key === weekArray.length - 1 ? ` ${item.day} ` : ` ${item.day} | `}
        </Text>
      ))
  )}
</ScrollView>;
```

I am getting output in the following way:
`Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday| Thursday| Friday | Saturday | Sunday`

I want to have onPress on all the days, so that when I click on any one of them, I can change style of that particular text. For example, if I click on Monday, then its color should change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's try:

```
  horizontal={true}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.horizontalView}>
  {weekArray.map((item, index, key) => ((
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ indexSelect : index})}>
           <Text key={key} style={[styles.TextStyle,
             {color : this.state.indexSelect === index ? '#ff0000' : '#000000'}]}>
             {key === weekArray.length - 1 ? ` ${item.day} ` : ` ${item.day} | `}
           </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))
  )}
</ScrollView>;
```